# CKEditor: Iconify code without using divs

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Hi all I've implemented a plugin (mentioned elsewhere in this site, BTW) that shows an icon rather than parts of edited document in *WYSIWYG* mode. You can see it in action here

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhKIofzLAp0

In order to do that I wrap the aforementioned snippets using div tags and use *CSS* to achieve desired behavior. Nonetheless , under certain circumstances divs are not suitable because they are used to layout elements in a page as well.

So my question is, how could I achieve the same results without using div tags nor any other trick that might have some impact on the output (i.e. something like fake elements or dummy containers, ...)?

Thnx in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how it is affecting the layout? Can I see an example? If your div has a unique class you should be able to control how it will display on the page, including not displaying at all.

Comment: It's used to edit _PHP_ pages which are the snippets hidden to show the icon. The fact is that the people offering the requirements, they want to obtain clean _PHP_ tags rather than snippets wrapped by `div`s.

Comment: Let's suppose there's _PHP_ code inside `span` tag . Normally text should be displayed inline once expanded but since there's a `div` wrapping _PHP_ block, it's just displayed different to what users expect ... things like that .